# Any code issues with putting an electrical box right next to wire on opposite stud?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance

Thinking of expanding a 2-gang box to a 3-gang box in a bedroom (light switches next to the door). I'm measuring about 6.25" between the studs. I want to use the following box, which is listed as having a width of 6.02".
[image]

It would be attached to the right stud. The left stud has a wire running down it, 12-2 Romex, that is taut and stapled to the stud. Seemingly, based on the measurements, there would be enough room for the box to fit in this space, even with the wire, and it wouldn't be squeezing the wire. Is there a reason this wouldn't be allowed provided the wire is not getting compressed?

Comment: as long you do not touch or damage the 12/2 cable you should be fine, but lets wait for the code guru to confirm

Comment: The measurements might come back to bite you.  It is going to be very close between enough space and too tight for squeezing the cable.

Comment:  Welcome @Logan to DIY and thanks for the well-formed question. Keep contributing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem with the cable running close to the box. It could even be up against it. It wouldn't be more compressed than the grips that will hold it in the box. Just make sure you're very careful cutting the drywall out to make it a three gang hole. I've seen people get all excited because the box will fit and their plan will work and then they nick or cut the NB cable while cutting the piece of drywall out. Now they've got a splice to worry about.

That's a great junction box. I've used them a lot and they are so much better than the old work boxes.